# How to calculate the technical debt?

Tags: sonarqube

We try to use Sonar to manage the software quality, like this page, we can get the technical debt. 
http://www.sonarqube.org/sqale-the-ultimate-quality-model-to-assess-technical-debt/

My question is, how to define the debt to fix a violation, remove some duplicated code or a new test case. Is there any calculate algorithm?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you get all the required information in the blog post: the SQALE methodology is perfectly explained on the [official SQALE website](http://www.sqale.org).

The blog post even mentions that there's a Sonar plugin that implements the methodology: the [Sonar SQALE plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/sqale/).

Comment: Thanks, I know the official site, but I cannot find the detail link to the calculation rule, could you advise me?

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't tell you how we implemented the SQALE methodology in our plugin (hey, come on, this is how we earn money that allows us to develop Sonar and make it available for free!)

Comment: Sorry, I don't want the algorithm of your plugin. We already buy Sonar's SQALE plugin and I just want to know is there any document to introduce the calculation base of SQALE? Or SQALE doesn't define calculation rule and let other company to implement directly?

Comment: OK Dennys, as you've already bought the SQALE plugin, then you get commercial support for it and you can directly write to "support AT sonarsource.com" to ask questions related to this plugin.

Comment: Hi Dennys, could you kindly share, what or how much information you could get from the support regarding your question?

Comment: Hi @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam Your link to the Sonar SQALE plugin seems to be dead, do you mind providing a new link ?